# How to check if running on UI thread in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading

How can I know if the running code is executed on the main thread (UI thread)?
With Swing I use the `isEventDispatchThread` method...

Comment: how is this question a duplicate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Doesn't look like there is a method for that in the SDK. The check is in the [`ViewRoot`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/view/ViewRoot.java;h=bef3e580a0c5ad037a0b495979ecf567c5a80995;hb=HEAD#l2681) class and is done by comparing `Thread.currentThread()` to a class member which is assigned in the constructor but never exposed.

If you really need this check you have several options to implement it:

1. catch the android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException
2. [`post`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) a `Runnable` to a view and check `Thread.currentThread()`
3. use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to do the same

In general I think instead of *checking* whether you're on the correct thread, you should just *make sure* the code is always executed on the UI thread (using 2. or 3.).

Comment: +1 for (3) < padding for the 15 limit >

Answer (score 126):

Use Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() to get the UI thread. You can check if it is the current thread using the following expression:

```
Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()
```

Comment: So just for the sake of explicitness, the actual check you can do is: (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread())

Comment: This anwer needs more love, thanks alot

Comment: How do you run this in junit?

Answer (score 85):

It is UI thread if:

```
Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()
```

Source AOSP source code: [`ManagedEGLContext.java#L100`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/dbc51de44fe4f9a7f81528204250de32ec405d39/opengl/java/android/opengl/ManagedEGLContext.java#L100), [`SharedPreferencesImpl.java#L470`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/dbc51de44fe4f9a7f81528204250de32ec405d39/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#L470), [`Instrumentation.java#L1650`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/dbc51de44fe4f9a7f81528204250de32ec405d39/core/java/android/app/Instrumentation.java#L1650) [and so on](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/search?q=Looper.myLooper%28%29%20==%20Looper.getMainLooper%28%29&ref=cmdform).

Comment: Short and sweet. Losing the `getThread()` is neat.

Comment: Worth noting although bbalazs mentions its from ICS, this is supported from API 1 onwards. So should be safe for all devices!

Comment: ➕1 for reference to AOSP source.

Comment: How do you run this in junit?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if you are in the main thread, you could maybe try:

```
Context c = **Get a Context**;
Thread.currentThread() == c.getMainLooper().getThread();
```

Of course, I could be wrong, and this could totally blow your app up.

Comment: A quick test suggests that this works well.

Comment: This works, but there's no need to get a context, see bbalazs's answer.