# Android: Asyctask is not work during JSON parsing when register user

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android - Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204079/android-caused-by-android-view-viewrootimplcalledfromwrongthreadexception)

I am using this example http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/ when i have registered my detail in registration form it save data in database but app crash it give below error

```
Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

my regsitration code is below

Register.java

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import com.example.petencare.library.JSONParser;
import com.example.petencare.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.example.petencare.library.UserFunctions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * Handles the user registration activity.
 * 
 */
public class Register extends Activity {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private EditText newUsername;
    private EditText newPassword;
    private EditText newConfiPass;
    private EditText newName;
    private EditText newPhone;
    private TextView Alreadyuser;
    private Button registerButton;
    private TextView registerErrorMsg;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";


     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration);


            newUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
            newPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_pass);
            newConfiPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_passre);
            newName      =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_name);
            newPhone      =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_mobile);
            registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
            Alreadyuser =    (TextView)findViewById(R.id.link_to_login);
            registerErrorMsg= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.register_error);

            Alreadyuser.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener(){ 
                public void onClick (View v){ 
                    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Login.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    // Close Registration View

                    finish();
                }
            });


            registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
                public void onClick (View view){ 

                new Registeruser().execute();

                }

            });

     }

            class Registeruser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Registering. Please wait...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    pDialog.show();

                }



            protected  String doInBackground(String... args) {
                    //Get user details. 
            String email = newUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = newPassword.getText().toString();
            String confirmpassword = newConfiPass.getText().toString();
            String name=           newName.getText().toString();
            String mobile =   newPhone.getText().toString();



            //Check if all fields have been completed.
            if (email.equals("") || password.equals("") || name.equals("") || mobile.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Please ensure all fields have been completed.",
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
            }

            //Check password match. 
            if (!password.equals(confirmpassword)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "The password does not match.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            newPassword.setText("");
                            newConfiPass.setText("");
                return null;
            }
             UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
             JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(email, password, name, mobile);


             // check for login response
             try {
                 if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                     registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                     String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                     if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                         // user successfully registred
                         // Store user details in SQLite Database
                         DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                         JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                         // Clear all previous data in database
                         userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                         db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_MOBILE), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                         // Launch Dashboard Screen
                         Intent dashboard1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                         // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                         dashboard1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                         startActivity(dashboard1);
                         // Close Registration Screen
                         finish();
                     }else{
                         // Error in registration
                         registerErrorMsg.setText("User already existed");
                     }
                 }
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }  
             return null;
            }

            @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();

            }


     }

}
```

I am using JSON parsing for sending data and i have a userfunction.java class which code is below

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;

public class UserFunctions {

    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    // Testing in localhost using wamp or xampp
    // use http://10.0.2.2/ to connect to your localhost ie http://localhost/
    private static String loginURL = "http://www.mywebsite.com/android_login_api/";
    private static String registerURL = "http://www.mywebsite.com/android_login_api/";

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        // return json
        // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject registerUser(String email, String password, String name, String mobile){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", mobile));

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function get Login status
     * */
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        int count = db.getRowCount();
        if(count > 0){
            // user logged in
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Function to logout user
     * Reset Database
     * */
    public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return true;
    }

}
```

please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Please google before posting a question, its asked nth time on StackOverflow.

Comment: Do not touch UI in another Thread - NEVER!!! Pass necessary data to the AsyncTask, process data in background, and update the UI in onPostExecute

Comment: @Lalit I am googling last 3 days but i am not understand how can i solve my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm getting error

> Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:
> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
> views.

means you are trying to access UI elements from `doInBackground` of [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). it's not possible to access Ui elements or Make `Toast` from Non UI Thread.

solution is move all EditText validation like code before starting AsyncTask and use `onPreExecute` of AsyncTask for getting `EditText` values in `doInBackground` ,use `onPostExecute` for Updating Ui when `doInBackground` execution completed

**EDIT :**

as on OP request move all validation inside button click as:

```
    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick (View view){ 

        //  PUT YOUR ALL VALIDATION HERE
        
        if(/* if validation success  */){
           
            // start AsyncTask here
            new Registeruser().execute();
         }
         else{
                // show validation error here
          }
        }

    });
```

Comment: wheni  put my validation code above asynctask it give error fileds are not resolve sorry i have not much knowledge about asynctask

Comment: @akash : move all validation code inside `registerButton` click and start `AsyncTask`  only when validation succeeded

Comment: i have do what you say but its give error i am doing this plzz see my code  registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: @akash : see my edit answer . i think my edit help you more in solving current issue.Thanks

Comment: thanku so much for this help

Comment: if you don't mind can you edit my above code

Comment: @akash : try it first yourself if still not solved then i will do for you k. first try your best

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `Toasts` in the doInBackground() method. As you are accessing UI in the `doInBackground()` to show the toasts and even why can't you move the validations' part before you start the asynctask.

Answer (score 0):

I think you Should to use `RunOnuithread` method or use `Handler` While in `doInBackground()`  of `Asynctask` Method.

this way use

```
    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // Already suggested by Dixit Patel:
        // Use the runOnUiThread method.
        // See his explanation.
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     @Override
         public void run() {
         if (!password.equals(confirmpassword)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "The password does not match.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        newPassword.setText("");
                        newConfiPass.setText("");

        }

     }
    });
```

Comment: @thanxxx and can i check all fields are fill are not in public void run()