# Update text in a TextView from a Thread

Tags: android

I have added a `TextView` to  a `RelativeLayout` that I already added a `SurfaceView` to. I can get the `TextView` to display text over my `SurfaceView`.

```
rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText(Integer.toString(GameScreen.score));
tv.setTextSize(50);
tv.setPadding(390, 50, 0, 0);
tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
rl.addView(renderView);
rl.addView(tv);
setContentView(rl);
```

Then in my GameScreen class's update method i put:

```
game.getTextView().setText(Integer.toString(score));
```

And it gives me the error:

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

What can I do to get around this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118301/android-viewrootimplcalledfromwrongthreadexception)

Comment: Thanks rkosegi I read it, but the solution from ankit made some sense, but I didn't understand it till @MustansarSaeed explained it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android update TextView in Thread and Runnable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716850/android-update-textview-in-thread-and-runnable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following which is the recommended way to update `Widget` on `UiThread`

```
game.getTextView().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    game.getTextView().setText(Integer.toString(score));
                }
            });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Superb thank you! This worked! It helped me understand the solution by @ankit as well!

Answer (score 1):

run your code in the UI thread. You cannot do UI operations from a worker thread.

```
your_context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){   
        game.getTextView().setText(Integer.toString(score));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, this solution is correct, but didn't make sense to me till I saw @Must solution below. But definitely up vote, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use this peice of code.. Um sure it will help you out !

```
private void runThread() {

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {

                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                           game.getTextView().setText(Integer.toString(score));
                        }
                    });

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    }.start();
```

Let me know if it works! :)

Comment: Thanks Vivek! The solution by @Must below worked but this helps me learn I really appreciate it!