# libgdx - How to access postRunnable

Tags: java, multithreading, libgdx

How can we mult-thread in libgdx ?

I tried:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      // do something important here, asynchronously to the rendering thread
      final int result = 10;
      // post a Runnable to the rendering thread that processes the result
      Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            Array<Integer> results = new Array<Integer>;
            Gdx.app.log("Thread1", "Worked");
            results.add(result);
         }
      });
   }
}).start();
```

I have read [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading) and it is official. But it did not tell me specifically how to access the array.

How can I access the result? through postRunnable

Answer (score 3):

You could subclass Runnable and keep the array as a member in that new subclass, there is a nice explanation for that approach here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7762490/4802055

Comment: I want to access the array results. Not send data into the thread.

Comment: Replace Data with the array you want to pass back.

Comment: @Tenfour04, i want to pass information out of the thread not into the thread

Comment: runOnUiThread() is for andorid activities, not for libgdx. So that link is not useful for me

Comment: ??? That linked answer does show how to pass data out of the thread back to the main thread. And you can replace runOnUIThread with Gdx.app.postRunnable.