# How to check if callback is executed in GUI Thread: Android

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

I have a application in which I receieve callbacks from the native layer and based on these callbacks I update the List UI on the screen.

How to I check of  the callbacks are being executed in  the UI thread only or in a separate thread?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845678/android-ui-thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way would be to just see what thread the ui is on with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread()
Then check it again later in the callback.