# Toast message not showing in main Looper?

Tags: android, toast

I know this is a old question with many answers, like what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845678/how-to-check-if-running-on-ui-thread-in-android). But I still cannot see my toast message.

I tried check the current thread like:

```
Log.d("DEBUG", "Main Looper: " + Looper.getMainLooper().toString() + ", Current Looper: " + Looper.myLooper().toString());
Log.d("DEBUG", "Main Thread: " + Looper.getMainLooper().getThread().toString() + ", Current Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().toString());

//and the log is like:
D/DEBUG﹕ Main Looper: Looper{420a9e68}, Current Looper: Looper{420a9e68}
D/DEBUG﹕ Main Thread: Thread[main,5,main], Current Thread: Thread[main,5,main]
```

so I think I'm in the main thread(ui thread), and I also tried toast in ui thread specifically:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "abc", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("DEBUG", "ui thread abc");
    }
});
```

I can see the log "ui thread abc" but the toast still didn't appeared.

Then I think maybe the toast is overlapped by other views so I tried to specify the location of toast like:
Toast toast Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "abc", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "abc", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Still get nothing. So what do you think is happening to my toast?

-------UPDATE

I'm in a activity with a vertical LinearLayout and several embedded horizontal LinearLayouts.
I got only two activities now and I'm toasting in the main acvitity.

I'm using a custom image slider and toasting in the onclick event, the onClickMethod is like below:

```
public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider) {
//        Log.d("DEBUG", "Main Looper: " + Looper.getMainLooper().toString() + ", Current Looper: " + Looper.myLooper().toString());
//        Log.d("DEBUG", "Main Thread: " + Looper.getMainLooper().getThread().toString() + ", Current Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().toString());
//        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), slider.getBundle().get("testMsg").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), slider.getBundle().get("testMsg").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//        Log.d("DEBUG", "Slider - " + slider.getBundle().get("testMsg").toString());

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "abc", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("DEBUG", "msg abc 123");


//        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "abc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
//        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
//        toast.show();
}
```

-------UPDATE 2

I just found that the action bar toast is not showing too, I did set the title element, I'm using a split action bar which is placed at the bottom of the screen.

Actually I can see all the toast messages before, then I made some change to the UI or some other stuffs, then all the toast disappeared. The problem is that I can't rollback to the older version which the toast is working good and I can't find the reason why they are gone now.

By the way after I added the custom image slider the toast is still good, and there isn't any other threads except the background thread which is auto switching the image slider.

Comment: use Activity Context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the problem again today when developing an other app, and did one last search again for that. And finally found that this seems like an [Android bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35013) which **if you disabled the notifications of the app, toast messages are disabled too**.

And all I have to do is go to Settings -> Apps -> My_App check the "Show Notifications" which is unchecked by myself occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

i faced same problem a month ago when i was trying to make toast from **doInBackground(String... params)** method of Async<>(Not UI thread), i used this and its working

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "whatever message ",
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

use `getApplicationContext()` or Activity context it will work

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "abc", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: thank you but getApplicationContext() is still not working, I tried with getBaseContext() before and double checked it just now.

Comment: getApplicationContext() will work please check.. i have tested it was working for me

Comment: yes I'm debugging in a real device and I tried with a Toast and a Log, I changed the log msg just in case, and I got the new log but didn't see the toast...

Comment: where you are this one, i mean is this code in activity or in Fragment ?. can you please post full code for better understanding